# Problem accessing second hard disk with Squeezebox server

Tags: filesystem, hard-drive, disk, disk-utility

I have recently re-purposed my old desktop PC as a 'server' running Ubuntu LTS 12.04. I want to use the machine as my primary squeezebox server in place of my HTPC MacMini (to reduce the strain on the MacMini). I managed to install squeezebox server without to much difficulty and added Music folder of my 'Home' folder to the library - all good and it worked fine.

I then realised that the disk was almost completely full and decided to install a second drive in the machine and move the music to that so that the primary drive could be used for other things. I installed a 1.5TB drive in the machine and formatted it as one partition with ext4 using Ubuntu's 'Disk Utility' app.

I then moved all my music to a 'Music' folder on the new drive using nautilus. The problem is that I cannot add the new drive/folder in the LMS web settings.

The old music folder was located at: /home//Music (This can be found fine by clicking browse in LMS web settings)

When I go to the settings page at 'Basic Settings','Media Folders' and click browse, I cannot find the new drive - it is not showing up.

The new drive is located at: `/media/mediadisk`

I can access the new drive without any problems using nautilus, or by navigating through the terminal, but if I use the 'browse' feature from within LMS web settings the folder cannot be found. (The 'mediadisk' drive is not showing up in the 'media' folder)

I have even tried pasting: `/media/mediadisk/Music` into the 'Media Folders' field but nothing works!

I must confess I am pretty new to Linux but if I was to guess I would say it was a problem with the permissions, right? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The new drive is not actually at `/media/mediadisk/Music`.  It is located at something like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`.  Try looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/352598/how-to-find-the-dev-name-of-my-usb-device) for more information.

Comment: This doesn't sound right.